# Form validation in javascript when drop down dependency is involved

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, validation

I have used ng-disabled for my form validation for ADD button.
i.e. **ng-disabled="conditionForm.$invalid"**. But , My form contains two text boxes which are hidden at first , and when a type is selected from drop down , only the respective Text box div should be visible. The Problem i'm facing is ,when the above ng-disabled validation is used , the ADD button is still disabled when one of the text box is selected and an input is provided. After the second input is also selected from the drop-down , then the ADD button is getting enabled.
**Can you please provide me with an alternate validation , where the ADD button can get enabled every time a value is selected from drop down and a valid input is provided.**

Comment: please show us your code

Answer (score 1):

If you're ng-disabled is on a form being valid or invalid it sounds like those may have required inputs set. If that is case look at using ng-required so you can explicitly set required based on expression. You can then control when the form is valid.

```
The exact answer: <a href="http://jsfiddle.net/yuobrupr/2">Answer</a>
```

Comment: ng-required does not work.It keeps the ADD button in enabled state only.

Comment: Just incase it wasn't clear the ng-required would not go on the add button but it would go on the hidden text areas

Comment: yeah . but , i was asking about the validation for ADD button in the form. I'm facing the issue in ADD button enable/Disable situation.                           When first option is selected from drop down, its text box appears and i have given a valid input into it.Still the ADD button is in disabled state.

Comment: The Button is getting enabled , only when the Second option is selected(after the first option) and  a valid input is provided into it.                ng-disabled is working as it has to work , but my question is ,In my functionality instead of using ng-disabled , Is there any alternate form validatior ?                                                                                                  #Thanks in Advance

Comment: From what i understand you want the button to be enabled when one or the other option is selected? I've created a jsFiddle to show that... hope this helps https://jsfiddle.net/yuobrupr/

Comment: Thanks @Raffaele , but the js fiddle you provided works when only one text box is involved.My requirement is , when option1 is selected, the option1 text box must appear and when option2 is selected from drop down , option2 text box must appear. Both the boxes must be in the same form. Then the ng-disabled validation is not working .   Hope you understood my problem !!

Comment: Apologies I'm not sure I do understand the problem. You have 1 form. In this form you have a drop down with 2 options. Then you have 2 text areas hidden. When option 1 selected text area 1 is displayed and text area 2 is hidden. When option 2 selected text area 1 is hidden and text area 2 is displayed. If a user selects option 1 and types in text area 1 the add button should be enabled. When a user selects option 2 and types in text area 2 the add button should be enabled? Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: yes @Raffaele . You got it right !! If you could come up with a solution , that would be appreciated.                                                                      #Thanks in Advance

Comment: That is exactly what my original solution was doing. I've updated it by adding in labels for the different textareas to make it more clear. hope this helps https://jsfiddle.net/yuobrupr/1/

Comment: @RaffaeleRizzetti : The code fails when we do it randomly. Try using your fiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/yuobrupr/1/ by entering text after selecting Option1 & option2 and by clearing the text or re-entering.  The ADD Button will get enabled.

Comment: apologies i see the error.. i've added a min length this should then prevent it from being empty... https://jsfiddle.net/yuobrupr/2/

Comment: @RaffaeleRizzetti : Yes. This works for all scenarios. 1 Vote up.

Comment: @RaffaeleRizzetti Can you please include a string validation for one text box and folder validation for another text box . If the validation fails , the ADD button remains disabled . Can you please help me with this thing !!

Comment: sorry i'm not sure i understand what you mean?

Comment: You have provided me a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/yuobrupr/2/         it helps when no validations are involved.                                                                  I just want your help in validating the text boxes ..

Comment: Like , My first text box should be validated for folder path  i.e.ng-pattern="/^([A-Z|a-z]:\\[^*|><>?\n]*)|(\\\\.*?\\.*)$/" required>      and my second text box should be validated for file path . i.e-ng-pattern="/^(([a-zA-Z]:)|(\\{2}\w+)\$?)(\\(\w[\w].*))(.jpg|.txt|.doc|.xls|.gif|.GIF|.exe|.pdf|.xml|.cvv|.dll)$/" required>                              When , the text box is empty or its validation fails , the ADD button must be disabled.

Comment: What kind of validation are you looking for? In that fiddle the text areas must have a min length of 1 meaning it effectively is required.

Comment: No, You dint get me. sorry if i am not clear .                                                  My Text boxes are for folder path and file path inputs.                One text box should accept a folder path (with a folder path validation) and the other text box should accept a file path.                                    When the text boxes are empty , A message is displayed inline - the text box should not be empty . and when the input in the text box is not valid , the message is : the input is not a valid folder path.

Comment: apologies for late response.... i've updated the fiddle to include showing error messages and keep the the button disabled for as long as the form is invalid... i've added an example of a pattern of numbers only but you can change that to whichever regular expression you want to check.. .https://jsfiddle.net/yuobrupr/3/